# CSS Drop Down menu Faulty

Tags: html, css

When I hover over my drop down menu, the text overlaps it and the menu goes away.

Link to site: http://stock-trade-101.com/market-indicators/

I would really appreciate help with this.

Can someone tell me what to add or change.

CSS Code:

```
#cssmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #232323;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #a0a0a0;
  font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  -webkit-transition: color .15s;
  -moz-transition: color .15s;
  -o-transition: color .15s;
  transition: color .15s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -90px;
  width: 180px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
  transition: all .3s .1s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 65px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fafafa transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  color: #323232;
  font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 206px;
  padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
  width: 180px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 190px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background-color: #cc2c24;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Comment: I can't get your site to load. Can you post the relevant HTML source or perhaps put this in JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry it still times out I'm afraid. Also in general it is best practice to include enough information in your question so that other's can still benefit from it, even after your site is fixed or your test site is taken down.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: We need your HTML too.

Comment: sorry. I think my server is down. not sure why. what do you want me to post on jsfiddle, the whole css code and html

Comment: i am a complete newbie. do you need the html of page or the html that goes with the CSS

Comment: We need the html & css and JS(if any) related to problem. i.e. in your case its the dropdown menu so provide us the code related to that.